# Does Payflow Link support recurring billing with CiviCRM?

Tags: payment-processor, paypal, recurring-contributions

I want to know if it's possible to use Payflow Link's recurring billing option with CiviCRM.

There is some information in the forum about how it needs to be implemented yet.. but it's unclear to me whether it's about using Recurring with Paypal Pro or with Payflow Pro. It looks like it's talking about using Payflow recurring with Website Payments Pro, which I didn't know was an option. Could someone please clarify? Thanks. https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=29346.0

Answer (score 2):

Last I looked into it PayflowLink supported it - but the code integration was not written for CiviCRM.

However, that code was written quite a while ago and I believe that paypal has moved on & now prefers a different interaction with them is used. That might mean adding recurring would create more work. However, I would note that it only changes the nature of the 'development gap' - the short answer is that extra work is required to get recurring payments to work with Payflow Link. If you want to do that work, or commission it then I can help give development advice on it - but you might want to look at whether you are better off using a processor with existing recurring support (e.g. IATS, Stripe, Authorize.net, eway etc).

Note that if you do look into IATS you should use this link http://home.iatspayments.com/civicrm-referral - if  you are referring yourself you can put the referrer $ to CiviCRM core team I believe